# Blender to Unity Issues

Tags: texturing, uv, unity, .fbx

I'm relatively new to Blender and extremely new to Unity and I'm facing a lot of issues with exporting my model from Blender to Unity.
I watched a lot of tutorials, yet my model is looking really distorted when I export it as an FBX and the textures are not working as well (I tried baking the textures, but they keep looking stretched when I apply them in Unity)

Please please help a beginner out, I'm losing my mind trying to figure out how to fix this

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the model looks distorted"? It looks good to me, doesn't it? Have you applied the scale before you exported the model? -- Where are textures stretched? What I clearly see is that the colors are different. What does the material in Blender look like? I'm not that familiar with Unity but are you sure the textures are used the way they should?

Comment: The second image doesn't show it properly but if you zoom in you could kinda see that there are some odd stripes when I apply the texture and I'm not certain if it's an issue with the textures themselves or the model. And yes I've applied the scale. In Blender, the material looks like wooden planks but they're stretched out in Unity. I've used the textures from Blenderkit.

Comment: In Blender, does the material only use the *Principled BSDF* node and the textures? If you have baked them they should look the same in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding that the scale of the model is distorted when you import into Unity, then your objects in Blender may have non-uniform scale. To fix this, ensure that you have applied the scale in Blender before export.

To do this, select all the objects that you wish to export and press Ctrl+A. Then in the dropdown menu, choose Scale.

Comment: Thanks for your response! And The scales are all good as I've applied all the transformations. My issue lies in the texturing mostly I believe.

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped your model, or are you using generated coordinates in Blender? Do you have more than one UV map on your objects?